# how to copy and deploy multiple logic apps to different RG

Tags: deployment, resources, move, new-operator, azure-logic-apps

I am having multiple logic apps in resorce group.How can i copy all and deploye to different RG. 
what is best way to do so?
I am not prefering Moving resorces.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you can download all of the logic apps to visual studio, from there create parameter files and build Azure DevOps build/release pipelines to different resource groups. Such as dev, test, uat & prod resource groups. I am using this strategy to build and govern over 300 logic apps for one of my customers. Now I started from Visual studio but you could easily download your current logic apps using the cloud explorer in visual studio or directly from the Azure portal.

One of the things you will have to look out for is the API-connections, they tend to create new ones even when not asked for.